# How can i calculate the age using the birth date from constructor?

Tags: java

```
 // main 
public class Application {
     public static void main(String[] args)  {

        StudentRepository myStudent = new StudentRepository();
    myStudent.addStudent("St","Rt","0742", "1993.03.04", PersonGender.MALE, "1930303");
    myStudent.addStudent("Sr","Ro","0742", "1994.03.04", PersonGender.MALE, "1940304");
    myStudent.addStudent("Se","Rb","0742", "1995.03.04", PersonGender.MALE, "1950305");
    myStudent.addStudent("Sm","Re","0742", "1996.03.04", PersonGender.MALE, "1950306");
    myStudent.deleteStudent("Stumer","Robert","0742", "1992.03.04", PersonGender.MALE, "null");
    myStudent.deleteStudent("Sr","Ro","0742", "1994.03.04", PersonGender.MALE, "1940304");
    myStudent.displayStudents();
    myStudent.calculateAge();// not working
 }
}


 // class StudentRepository
  public class StudentRepository  {


private final Map<String, Student> students = new HashMap<>();


public void addStudent(String firstName, String lastName, String phoneNumber, String birthDate, PersonGender gender, String id) {
    Student student = new Student(firstName, lastName, phoneNumber, birthDate,  gender, id);

    if (students.containsKey(id)) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Student already exist!");
    }
   students.put(id, student);
}

public void deleteStudent(String firstName, String lastName, String phoneNumber, String birthDate, PersonGender gender, String id)  {
    Student student = new Student(firstName, lastName, phoneNumber, birthDate,  gender, id);

    if (id == null) {
        throw new NullPointerException("ID is null");
    }

    if (students.containsKey(id)) {
        students.remove(id);
    }
    else {
        throw new NullPointerException("The student does not exist");
    }

}

public void displayStudents() {
    System.out.println("The student list:");
    displayCollection(students.values());
}

private <T> void displayCollection(Collection<T> collection) {
    for (T item : collection) {
        System.out.println(item);
    }
}


public  int calculateAge(LocalDate birthDate) {
    String birthday = "1993.03.04";
    birthDate = LocalDate.parse(birthday, 
    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy.MM.dd"));
    int ageInYears = calculateAge(birthDate);
    Period period = Period.between(birthDate, LocalDate.now());
    return period.getYears();
}

// class Student
public  class Student {

private final String firstName;
private final String lastName;
private final String phoneNumber;
private final String birthDate;
private final PersonGender gender;
private final String id;



public Student(String firstName, String lastName, String phoneNumber, String birthDate, PersonGender gender, String id) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    this.birthDate = birthDate;
    this.gender = gender;
    this.id = id;

}



@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
    Student student = (Student) o;
    return Objects.equals(firstName, student.firstName) &&
            Objects.equals(lastName, student.lastName) &&
            Objects.equals(phoneNumber, student.phoneNumber) &&
            Objects.equals(birthDate, student.birthDate) &&
            gender == student.gender &&
            Objects.equals(id, student.id);
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hash(firstName, lastName, phoneNumber, birthDate, gender, id);
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Student{" +
            "firstName='" + firstName + '\'' +
            ", lastName='" + lastName + '\'' +
            ", phoneNumber='" + phoneNumber + '\'' +
            ", birthDate='" + birthDate + '\'' +
            ", gender=" + gender +
            ", id='" + id + '\'' +
            '}';
}
```

}

Date code is the fourth parameter of the constructor and below it si the method that I implemented for age calculation. The requirement is to: retrieve all students with Age X (for each student the age must be calculated, not stored in a field). * exceptions: age is negative. I this moment I am learnig JAva, any suggestion for improvement are welcome

Comment: Don't use `java.util.Calendar` and `java.util.Date` for calculations, they are outdated for good reasons... Use `java.time` instead (if you are running Java 8 or higher, which I assume you are).

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you are able / allowed to use `java.time`, you can calculate the age of a person passing his / her date of birth in a single statement / just a few lines.

See this example:

```
public static int getAgeInFullYears(LocalDate birthDate) {
    Period period = Period.between(birthDate, LocalDate.now());
    return period.getYears();
}
```

You will have to pass the date of birth as an instance of `java.time.LocalDate`, which you could parse from a `String` (formatted as the ones in your question code) before, see this example usage:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // provide the date of birth as String
    String birthday = "1993.03.04";
    // parse it to a LocalDate using a formatter that parses the String format
    LocalDate birthDate = LocalDate.parse(birthday, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy.MM.dd"));
    // then calculate the years using the method
    int ageInYears = getAgeInFullYears(birthDate);
    // and print some result statment
    System.out.printf("The person is %d years old (date of calculation %s)",
                    ageInYears,
                    LocalDate.now());
}
```

The output would be this:

```
The person is 27 years old (date of calculation 2020-06-11)
```

**Edit:**

The easiest way to modify your current code would be to add the calculation method that first parses the date from the `String` attribute and then calculates the age using suitable classes.
You could do it like this:

```
class Student {
    private String birthDate;

    (...) // irrelevant code omitted for brevity

    public int getAgeInYears() {
        // parse the date of birth from the String attribute
        LocalDate dateOfBirth = LocalDate.parse(birthDate,
                                            DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy.MM.dd"));
        // then calculate the age in years at date of execution
        return Period.between(dateOfBirth, LocalDate.now()).getYears();
    }
}
```

Comment: :The requirement is to: retrieve all students with Age X (for each student the age must be calculated, not stored in a field).

  * exceptions: age is negative

Comment: @RSA Where in your question did you mention this requirement?

Comment: @RSA For anything in that direction, we need to know your `class Student` and maybe even the `class StudentRepository`.

Comment: any suggestion? how should I modify the code? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
int age = (new Date().getTime() - birthDate.getTime())/(1000 * 60*60 * 24*365):
```

Comment: Never use the outdated date/time API. Check the [answer by deHaar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62327107/10819573) and [this article](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the new [`java.time`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes, which are more convenient.

```
final LocalDate birth = birthDate.toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate();
final LocalDate now = LocalDate.now();
final int age = Period.between(birth, now).getYears();
```